# WPF DataGrid, selected row color on DataGrid SelectedItem Change in MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, datagrid

I have a WPF DataGrid that when I add a new item via a collection, I select that new item (row) using C# in the MVVM

```
// Adding the new item (which will create a new row)
ItemSourceCollection.Add(object);

// The itemSource would have refreshed, so now assign the SelectedItem of the grid
SelectedItem = ItemSourceCollection.Where(x => x.Id == Id).FirstOrDefault();
```

This works well as the row is selected. However, the row color doesn't match the color of when the user actually clicks on the row.

The xaml for the selected row color

```
<DataGrid.Resource>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" 
               Color="#FF0000"/>
 </DataGrid.Resource>
```

So is it possible to use this color when a new row is added to the collection via code?

Comment: Has `DataGrid` got focus? Did you try `myDataGrid.Focus()`?

Comment: The code above is in the VIewModel so I won't be able to get to the DataGrid control itself. However, I don't mind going to the View so I will have a look from that prospective

Comment: You can set focus in the view but there is different color for selected item when it's focused and when it's not

Comment: Oh right, I didn't know, cheers, so how do I set the color of the SelectedItem then? cheers!

Comment: Are you using .NET 4.5?

Comment: No .NET4.0, but I can use it 4.5

Comment: try setting this `<SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="#FF0000"/>` as well

Comment: Thank you, that has seemed to work, if you make an answer, I will mark it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is caused by the fact that there is a different brush for when selected item has focus and when it has not. So you either need to set focus or add this

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="#FF0000"/>
```

to `DataGrid.Resources`. If you would be using .NET 4.5 there is dedicated brush for that and you would need to add

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey}" Color="#FF0000"/>
```